# How can I get a raw print queue in the Print & Scan menu?

Tags: printing

I have set up a raw queue (without a PPD) in CUPS via the command line and lpadmin.

It works perfectly if I print files via the command line and lp, but it doesn't appear when I try to add it via Add Printer in Print & Scan in System preferences. As such I cannot print from inside applications.

Any idea on how to get the printer to appear in the list of available printers?

Thanks.

Comment: show us your work !

Comment: @buscar: Pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/ytztLeWr